# How to abandon current command in MySQL CLI?

Tags: linux, command-line, mysql

In the MySQL/MariaDb command line client, if I have the cursor in the middle of a long query and I want to abandon that command I have to

1. reposition cursor at the end of the line
2. check whether the end of the line already has `;` or `\G` or `\g`, and if so backspace to delete those.
3. if the query (often loaded onto the current line by accessing history) contains several SQL commands, I would need to ensure that none of those was going to execute by replacing all `;`s with `\c`
4. append `\c`
5. hit Enter.

Or,

1. reposition cursor at start of line
2. type `#` to make the whole thing a comment
3. hit Enter.

This is a huge amount of work for a common need. In bash, I hit `Ctrl-C` and it gives me a fresh command prompt ignoring whatever else was on that line. But of course, do that in MySQL and it exits the whole client.

Is there a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 3):

A couple shorter options:

- <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> to get to the beginning of the line, followed by <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> to (forward) kill the entire line.
- <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> to get to the end of the line, followed by <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> to (backward) kill the entire line.

Comment: Can't use `Ctrl-A` because I'm always in [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) but the E, U, one looks a hopeful shortcut to learn, thank you.